# Ubuntu for laptop not on internet

Tags: system-installation

I want to download Ubuntu for a laptop that cannot connect to the Internet. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You do not necessarily need an internet connection to install Ubuntu, the installer iso image you download and burn to a DVD or USB drive is enough. Once the system is installed, you can install and update  software without direct internet connection by downloading them elsewhere using the methods described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Comment: You can also buy an USB stick with 16.04 https://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Answer (score 0):

What country are you in? If it's the US or UK, there's a fair chance your local supermarket will have a Linux magazine. They've usually got one version of Ubuntu or another on their cover desk, even more likely at the moment since 17.04 has just dropped.

Comment: Not just the US or UK. :)